# Static Map API that supports HTTPS requests and is free

Tags: google-maps, https

Any options out there?  Google Static Maps with SSL (HTTPS) is only available to Premier members.  Bing's Open Map API seems to have the same restricts.  Any other ideas?  I'm debating whether to schedule a cronjob to wget over http and dump the images I need into a folder (named after the content object IDs that reference them), but I'd rather find a free map API (or something less klugey) that supports HTTPS requests.

Comment: Just as a side-note: An HTTPS handshake isn't trivial on server resources. I imagine that free maps don't fancy the load, hence premium-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up a non-SSL virtual host for the map pages; I learned that it wasn't a requirement to have those pages encrypted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [streetdirectory maps](http://www.streetdirectory.com/api/widgets/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [static map images at OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Staticmaps), perhaps.

Comment: Doesn't look like they support SSL either, but thanks anyways.